# UTF-8 encoding and Notepad with LaTeX

Tags: windows, accents, input-encodings

I have written some LaTeX commands in a separate file, say `foo.tex` and include them in my LaTeX document.

Only after I edit `foo.tex` with Notepad (default editor in Windows), I get the following error message when compiling :

```
Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with LaTeX
```

I suspect that Notepad alters my text file, which is saved as previously with the UTF-8 encoding. How can I prevent it ?

Comment: The answer is that `foo.tex` is *not* UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Windows system's encoding is ISO isn't it?

Comment: According to Notepad, both files are in "UTF-8" encoding. However, I suspect that various encodings may be called "UTF-8" by Notepad.

Comment: On GNU/Linux, you can try `file --mine foo.tex` to get the 'charset', but it is not foolproof....

Comment: You might try moving to Notepad2 or notepad++; both load about as fast as notepad and won't screw up your EOL markers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Very likely notepad puts a byte order marker (BOM) at the start of the file. The "character" is invisible, but present. See also:
[How to make notepad to save text in utf-8 without bom?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8432584)

For TeX files that are input after package `inputenc` is loaded, BOM can be disabled by:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FEFF}{}
```