# utf8x character fails in the table of contents every second time i compile

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, unicode

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{ø}
\end{document}
```

First time I compile this, I get an `ø` in the table of contents.
Second time I compile this, the `ø` turns into `[Pleaseinsertintopreamble]`, 
and this goes on and on.

What should I do in order to get an `ø` every time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Harish I would suggest to use utf8 instead of ucs/utf8x, but if for some reason you really need utf8x you must prerender the offending unicode character:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\PrerenderUnicode{ø}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{ø}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, the thing is I do need utf8x

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: I use package "alltt" to include txt-files with æøå, which fails with utf8

Comment: I don't see a reason why these chars should fail, you should better ask about it in a new question (with an example).

Comment: @Coolwater I tried `alltt` with `utf8` and had no problem. You should also do `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, but this just improves the typesetting, without it I have no problem either.

Comment: @egreg when i type `\input{doc.txt}` in alltt environment, compiling gives error when using utf8 without x: `! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with LaTeX.`.

Comment: @Coolwater A minimal example is needed. Does the input file have Greek letters?

Comment: @egreg The error occurs when i compile: 
`\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{alltt}
\begin{document}
\begin{alltt}
\input{doc.txt}
\end{alltt}
\end{document}`

Where doc.txt is saved in UTF-8-format by notepad.exe. It doesnt matter whether doc.txt is just empty or as usual contains the characters æ ø å ž š õ ü ö ä ÿ. Using utf8x makes it work though.

Comment: @Coolwater Notepad is known for adding the BOM to its UTF-8 encoded files and that is the cause of your problem. See [UTF-8 encoding and Notepad with LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154101/) Better cure the disease than just the symptoms.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` instead of `utf8x`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{ø}
\end{document}
```

[image]