# Metapost file fails to compile

Tags: metapost

I have what I think is a plain text .mp file made on notepad++, it chokes on the first line (whatever I put on the first line). Any ideas?
This is MetaPost, version 1.999 (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX) (kpathsea version 6.2.1)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/metapost/base/mpost.mp
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/metapost/base/plain.mp
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.005) ) (./hyperbola.mp
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1 ´
     ╗┐% Experiment

Comment: Looks like a BOM (byte order mark)

Comment: Perhaps related: [UTF-8 encoding and Notepad with LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154101/5764)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is notepad++. Once opened in MS notepad and saved as an ANSI file it works!